# DELETE causing a redirect loop?

Tags: postgresql, express

I have an express app with a postgres backend where a user can add/delete recipes, and each time they do so they get an updated list of recipes. Adding a recipe is fine, but when I delete one it seems to get stuck in a redirect loop. In `app.js` I have

```
router.get('/delete/:d', delRec.deleteRecipe);
```

which calls the following code

```
exports.deleteRecipe = function(req, res){
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
    client.query('DELETE FROM recipes WHERE recipe_name = ', [req.params.d], function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      } else if (result) {
        pg.end();
        console.log('deleting');
      }
    });
  });
  res.redirect('recipes');
};
```

If I try delete a recipe, `console.log('deleting')` produces

```
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
deleting
```

The `recipes route` is below (sorry that it's so convoluted)

```
router.get('/recipes', function(req, res) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
      recipes = result.rows;

      for(var d in recipes) {
        if (recipes.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
          recipeList[d] = recipes[d].recipe_name;
        }
      }
      res.render('recipes', {recipes: recipes, recipeList: recipeList});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Show us your recipes route

Comment: added it now, apologies for the spaghetti-ness

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the issue. But with your errors you should be sending a response as well as logging your errors. Currently you are only logging the errors to the console. This could possibly be the root of your problem since the requests may not be getting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that causes your issues is `res.redirect('recipes');`

Firstly, as @Jordonias pointed out, you should place this line in your db query's callback.

Second, I think the line redirects you from `YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/delete/:d` to `YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/delete/recipes` and not to `YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/recipes`, which generates an infinite redirection loop. Absolute vs relative paths is a very common pitfall.

So you should change your code to `res.redirect('/recipes');`